# Sizes: "n inches or above" OR "n inches or more"

Tags: word-choice

When we talk about sizes, such as the width of a doorway, what is the correct word to use in the following sentence, *above* or *more*?

> If the width of the doorway is 40 inches or **{above/more}**, *dependent clause*.

Comment: "40 inches or more" is correct.

Comment: "More" would be the most natural in any case, but especially so when describing a "width" rather than a "height."

Comment: @EthanBolker "40 inches or above" isn't incorrect even if a lot of people would choose "more". I would probably say "If the width of the doorway is 40 inches or wider". "Above" in this sense is "greater than some other number", not "higher in position".

Comment: @ColleenV I agree that "or above" isn't wrong.   Just a little strange (to my ear). "Above" for width would be OK too.I would say "the width is at least 40 inches", so avoiding "or more" as well.

Comment: @EthanBolker You may want to avoid stating one option is "correct" (implying the other is not). Learners tend to take "correct" and "incorrect" to mean "grammatical/ungrammatical" instead of "more widely used/less popular". Often there may be difference in formality where one word might be preferred in a particular context but not used much colloquially.

Comment: @ColleenV Fair point. If my comment were an answer I'd edit it. Perhaps you can post an answer.

Comment: I'm not answering the question, I'm just pointing out that your comment isn't accurate. If your comment were an answer, I would have commented on it :)

Comment: By the way, the first clause in the example sentence is a dependent clause. It would presumably be followed by an independent clause.

Comment: I'd have gone for 'greater' rather than either of the suggestions.